# How can I install Windows 7 alongside Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows, windows-7

I am currently using the latest version of **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS**

I would like to install windows 7 alongside with Ubuntu. I saw a girl running windows 7 alongside ubuntu, when she turn on her computer, he got 2 option, one to open ubuntu and another to open windows 7.

Can anyone please give me a suggestion that how can I run Windows 7 alongside with my current OS ubuntu.

I was trying to install windows 7 in another free drive but it's saying me- "Setup was unable to create a new system partition or locate an existing system partition. See the Setup log files for more information."

Can anyone please give me a solution.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is this really a Ubuntu question? Or is it a "Windows won't install" question? If there's enough free space on a hard drive somewhere but windows won't use it, that sounds like windows' problem. It used to be easier to install windows first, and then ubuntu (windows liked to erase grub & leave no trace of how to boot ubuntu). Can the windows installer see all your partitions, and it just won't use the one you want? Could try completely erasing a partition to make space for windows, but that's just a guess. What's the "setup log files" say? The answer's probably in there.

Comment: See this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Is ubuntu is your primary operating system.Who the partition of your hard disk.If all three partition are logical then you have to remove ubuntu first the install windows .Upload the 
$sudo parted -i
So we can tell you step by step how to go through dual booting your computer.

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu is my primary OS, all other is logical. My one logical drive is free, so I'm trying to install the Windows 7 in that Logical disk. I created the logical drive in NTFS, but it's saying me same message- "Setup was unable to create a new system partition or locate an existing system partition. See the Setup log files for more information."

Can you please give me a step by step how can I dual boot my computer.

Comment: First of all make a bootable pen drive or DVD.Then go to biso menu of your computer change the boot priority to your bootable device .Then boot the windows from your bootable medium .Then click on install now after some default choices you will see the partition of your disk choice your partition in which you want to install your windows .Then from downside you will see an option of formate select it .After doing so that partition will go to unallocated space then choice that space make a new partition and in that install your windows.

Comment: Some more things to add .After formating partition delete it and then form unallocated space make new partition.